# Issues when subtracting a float value in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that subtracts decimal values from a number but when I input certain values it returns a long series of decimals instead of the correct value.

I am trying to subtract 2.9 from 3 and instead of getting 0.1 as the value I am getting 0.099999999999. I have tried playing with the values of both the starting and subtracting numbers. Every time however there is a value I subtract that gives me a result like this and breaks the code. Is there a way to stop this from happening/

Comment: If this isn't the most repeatedly asked question on SO, it's got to be close.

Comment: If you start with strings and cast directly to Decimal you get your result, but yes in general floating point math often "seems" broken. `print(decimal.Decimal("3.0") - decimal.Decimal("2.9"))`

Comment: Are you always dealing with single digit precision after the decimal?  applying `round(x,1)`  might help you get a result that looks more like you want.

Comment: Do you know [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/103162.103163)?

Answer (score -1):

Computer hardware has limitations when it comes to floating point arithmetic. Check the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for more information but the opening is as follows:

> Floating-point numbers are represented in computer hardware as base 2 (binary) fractions. For example, the decimal fraction 0.125 has value 1/10 + 2/100 + 5/1000, and in the same way the binary fraction 0.001 has value 0/2 + 0/4 + 1/8. These two fractions have identical values, the only real difference being that the first is written in base 10 fractional notation, and the second in base 2.

> Unfortunately, most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions. A consequence is that, in general, the decimal floating-point numbers you enter are only approximated by the binary floating-point numbers actually stored in the machine.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: I clarified computer hardware instead of python, thanks for the catch to be more specific.